# LinQ: mostar lista de padres e hijos que dependan de un valor del modelo

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Tengo dos modelos, Category and ExternalResources:

**Category**

```
public partial class Category
{
    public long CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> ParentCategoryID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Subcategories { get; set; }
    public virtual Category ParentCategory { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ExternalResource> ExternalResources { get; set; }
}
```

**ExternalResources**

```
public partial class ExternalResource
{
    public string DisplayText { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public long CategoryID { get; set; }
    public int ExternalResourceID { get; set; }
    public bool SupportItem { get; set; }
    public bool IsInActivity { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

La variable llamada *IsInActivity* es la variable que uso para saber si mostrarlo en la lista o no.

Quiero mostrar una lista de los padres y sus hijos que tengan la variable *IsInActivity* como **true**.

Hice esta función que regresa casi lo que requiero pero no muestra los padres que tienen solo hijos seleccionados como true.

```
public List<Category> ContainsResources(List<Category> qry)
{
                List<Category> lstResourceIsInActivity = qry.Where(c => c.ExternalResources.Any(r => r.IsInActivity)).Select(c => new Category
                {
                    CategoryID = c.CategoryID,
                    Name = c.Name,
                    ParentCategoryID = c.ParentCategoryID,
                    Subcategories = c.Subcategories.Where(b => b.ExternalResources.Any(r => r.IsInActivity) && b.ParentCategoryID != null).Select(b => new Category
                    {
                        CategoryID = b.CategoryID,
                        Name = b.Name,
                        ParentCategoryID = b.ParentCategoryID,
                        ExternalResources = b.ExternalResources.Where(r => r.IsInActivity).ToList()
                    }).ToList(),
                    ParentCategory = c.ParentCategory,
                    ExternalResources = c.ExternalResources.Where(r => r.IsInActivity).ToList()
                })
             .ToList();

                return lstResourceIsInActivity;
    }
```

Hay alguna forma de hacer esto con LinQ?

UPDATE

[image: foto]

Comment: Que te devuelve exactamente?

Comment: @lDanny7 me devuelve una lista con los padres que tienen seleccionados a sus hijos pero no me muestra los padres que solo tienen dentro a otro padre(subcategoria) con hijos seleccionados

Comment: Entiendo que tienes las categorias padres A,B,C y D, y dentro de A tienes las categorias A.1, A.2, A.3 .... Y lo que te devuelve ahora mismo es A con A.1, A.2, A.3 aunque A.2 no tenga un IsInActivity true, no? Y quieres que te devuelva A con A.1, A.3 solo

Comment: @lDanny7 mas bien seria: tengo padres A,B,C y D, y dentro de A puede tener hijo1, hijo2 y/o subpadre1, subpadre2. Lo que me muestra es todos los padres si tiene hijos como true pero no me muestran los padres si no tiene algun hijo1 en true pero si su subpadre1(dentro de este con un hijo en true)

Comment: @lDanny7 basicamente me refiero que un padre puede tener o solo hijos o hijos y subpadres, pero si un subpadre tiene un hijo en true pero no un hijo principal, la función no me muestra el padre principal, solo muestra los padres con algún hijo principal en true.

Comment: Es Entity Framework? porqué mejor no haces un join? recuerda que EF convierte el query de linq a sql, y así como lo tienes puede que no se esté pasando al sql adecuado.

Comment: Yo he leido varias veces la pregunta y no lo tengo claro todavía. Intuyo que lo que quieres es "aplanar" la colección, con lo que necesitas usar `SelectMany`. Pero tal vez si pusieses un ejemplo podría darte algo mas exacto

Comment: Se agradecería un diagrama donde muestre los datos que tiene y con los que pretende quedarse, ya que con eso lo tendriamos más claro, ya que entre subpadre tiene un hijo y luego un hijo principal no me aclaro.

Comment: @Pikoh subí un pequeño diagrama, basicamente es el padre que puede contener un hijo y/o un subpadre que tambien contiene hijos, pero en la lista no me muestra los padres que tienen subpadres con hijos seleccionados si este padre princpal no tiene hijos principales seleccionados como true

Comment: Sigo pensando que debes usar SelectMany para aplanar la coleccion y poder acceder a todos los hijos. Podrias poner un ejemplo con código añadiendo un par de elementos y la salida esperada. Echa un vistazo a [mcve]

Comment: @Pikoh bueno ya resolví mi problema, la verdad era algo sencillo pero no lo veía claro, pero muchas gracias por su ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

La forma mas sencilla de hacerlo seria crear una función en la clase Category. Al ser una clase partial (posiblemente generada mediante EntityFramework) podemos crear otro fichero con el mismo namespace de la clase Category.

```
public partial class Category
{
    public bool FiltrarIsInActivity()
    {
        if (ExternalResources != null)
        {
            // Filtramos external resources por IsInActivity
            ExternalResources = ExternalResources.Where(e => e.IsInActivity).ToList();

            // Si no existe algun external resources la categoria no esta activa
            if(!ExternalResources.Any()){
               return false;
            }

            // Filtramos las subcategorias por la funcion actual
            Subcategories = Subcategories.Where(s => s.FiltrarIsInActivity()).ToList();


            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

El código de la función ContainsResources sería el siguiente:

```
public List<Category> ContainsResources(List<Category> qry)
{
        var filtrados = qry.Where(c => c.FiltrarIsInActivity());

        return filtrados.ToList();
}
```